# Merge tags "baltic-sea" and "ostersjon"

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tag **[östersjön](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/ostersjon)** is a *localized* version of the tag **[baltic-sea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/baltic-sea)** and should be added as a synonym of the **[baltic-sea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/baltic-sea)**.

Other (rare) synonyms of the **[baltic-sea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/baltic-sea)** include:

- baltiska-havet
- baltiska-sjon
- itameri
- mer-baltique

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the heads-up. Tags were merged and synonym added. I have not added the other synonyms yet. I would rather wait to see if anyone actually creates those tags. The reason being that as of now we have 3 questions tagged [baltic-sea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baltic-sea) which seems to show that it's not a hot topic for Travel. This means that the likelihood of new questions with new tags being asked is quite low.

Comment: The [tag:caribbean] and [tag:san-francisco-bay-area] tags cover both the region and the body of water; might it be beneficial to merge this one with [tag:baltic-region]?